# Error Occuring: Value for SASL_DB_PATH_ATTR for cyrus-sasl with lmdb

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sasl, lmdb, cyrus

While I was building cyrus-sasl with lmdb and open-ssl for windows (as recommend by it Installation guide), I'm encountering some linking error, especially for building sasldb.lib in visual studio 2022, I have properly linked the path for lmdb, open-ssl and gssapi as well. But, the problem occurs for for building sasldb.lib.

This is the setup for the project property for sasldb solution. I'm currently using latest Window SDK for this build-up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3GiS.png)

This is the include directory setup of sasldb solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT1QO.png)

This is the directory where all the necessary include header for lmdb is present ( just for reference )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzjEO.png)

This is library directory setup for sasldb solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvYMe.png)

This the necessary directory for all the library header for lmdb present.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfEWZ.png)

I have also specified the name of lmdbd.lib for to used in the property of sasldb solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvLst.png)

This is the section of code which is creating the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06y3L.png)

The error log for this build-up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jRe0.png)

Can anybody advice me on this ?
This is the only problem I am facing while building up.
I'm kind of new at this.
I'm trying to use it for building libVNC C library, which I'm using for my project.

Edit: Sorry for earlier. I didn't give the details about the problem I was facing.

Comment: Usually others share the code and the output as text, so no need to go back and forth between pictures and the question.